# How to make APP_GUARD run before any Imports module in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-jwt, nestjs-mongoose

I have a JWT validate middleware like bellow

```
app.module.ts

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot(global.SkeletonConfig.MONGODB_URI),
    UserModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: AuthGuard,
    },
    JwtService,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And the User module

```
user.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([mongooseModuleFunction(User)])],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService, User],
})
```

```
mongooseModuleFunction.ts
export function mongooseModuleFunction(schema: Schema<any>) {
  return {
    name: schema.name,
    useFactory: mongooseFactory(schema),
    inject: [REQUEST],
  }
}
export function mongooseFactory(schema: Schema<any>) {
  return async (req: Request) => {
    

    schema.set('collection', req.collectionName)
    return UserSchema
  }
}
```

When I call a request, NestJS will run the `MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([mongooseModuleFunction(User)])` before the `AuthGuard`

How can I change this behavior? I need to parse the JWT payload first and put it into the request to identify which collection will be used for each request.